# UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\xfd' in python 2.7

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, lxml, command-prompt

I download different Companies name from different websites from my localhost sometimes i face this problem and that is interrupt the download procedure.My script is working fine for others country but when i download Czech Republic this type of error is occurred.

> Total companies processed so far:0 Traceback (most recent call last): 
>   File "process1.py", line 261, in 
>       print "Company Name: "+hit.text   File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 12, in encode
>       return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map) UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\xfd' in
>   position 3 3: character maps to

my code is here :

```
if companyAlreadyKnown == 0:
                            for hit in soup2.findAll("h1"):
                                print "Company Name: "+hit.text
                                pCompanyName = hit.text
                                flog.write("\nCompany Name: "+str(pCompanyName))
                                companyObj.setCompanyName(pCompanyName)
```

I don't know why it is happened.Any suggestion in this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Czech language contains a lot of non ASCII characters. `u'\xfd'` is a unicode representation of `ý`. You need to decode `UTF-8`. An even better solution is to detect what encoding the website you are scraping uses and decode to that one.

```
if companyAlreadyKnown == 0:
    for hit in soup2.findAll("h1"):
        company_name = hit.text.decode('utf-8')

        print "Company Name: " + company_name

        flog.write("\nCompany Name: " + pCompanyName)
        companyObj.setCompanyName(company_name)
```

Comment: thanks mate !!! it solved my problem but fact is that when ever i try to download Iran the whole company name is fetched but it cannot store the MySQL server...i just follow the same procedure for my scripting..do u have any idea how to solve that problem ......... @dm295

Comment: Try to check MySQL log file for error messages, also check MySQL encoding settings